# Feed char array into stdin

Tags: c++, c, parsing, yacc, lex

I am writing a parser for a mini scripting language. Some of my grammar rules require jumping to a different location in the file to obtain information. There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to accomplish this. So, I was thinking about loading my data files into a `char` array array and parsing line by line. This will allow me to jump all over the array with ease.

My question is, is it possible to feed `char` arrays (i.e. `char *`) into `stdin`, so I can easily invoke the `yyparse()` function as needed.

Comment: Yes, you can use pipe() and dup2() to make *stdin* be the output end of a pipe, and then feed any data source you have available into the input end.

Comment: @ChrisStratton
can you provide a simple example? If you could, make sure you post it as an answer so I can select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As a side note, from a design point of view it's probably a *bad idea* to have a grammar that *requires* jumping all over the input string.

Comment: @Rufflewind thing is, I have to be able to support offsets. Think of it as a branch statement in an assembly program. How else would you handle labels and offsets without jumping all over the place?

Comment: you could use `std::stringstream` to use stream interface starting with `string` data. Don't think that it's a good idea that the parse function read directly from stdin. You should at least abstract the reading-writing off the parsing. The parsing function should receive `char*`, `buffer`, `stream`, `mapped file`, something like that and parse using this.

Comment: @NetVipeC as far as I know, the yylex() and yyparse() functions use stdin (i.e. FILE * stdin) which is by default set to read data off keyboard. It's easy to force stdin to read off a file. I am not sure how to involve std::stringsteam in all of this

Comment: @BrianLindsey The parser's job is to convert your input into a concrete syntax tree.  Its grammar should not depend on things like "labels" and "offsets" that are of interest only to the semantic analyzer, unless your have a *really* context-sensitive grammar...

Comment: `How else would you handle labels and offsets without jumping all over the place?` The same way pretty much every assembler does it - two-pass compilation. On the first pass, you remember the offset of every label when you encounter it, and leave space in the jump instructions that mention labels you haven't seen yet. Then, after you've seen all the labels, you patch up those instructions with now-known label offsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to read input from `stdin`, or even from a file. You can use [`yy_scan_string`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Scanning-Strings) (and friends) to feed a string into the lexer, and use `yywrap` to provide the next string. (However, note that tokens cannot span two buffers. That can be an issue for line-by-line parsing if your language allows multi-line tokens, like string literals.)

Also, you can redefine [`YY_INPUT`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-YY_005fINPUT) in order to provide input in any order and from any source you like. That avoids the multi-line token issue, too.

Having said all that, the project strikes me as a little dubious. The usual reason for buffer management in `(f)lex` is to implement features like C's `#include`, but that doesn't sound like what you're planning.